# Dropdown menu showing gap in between menu and sub menu?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am customizing wordpress twentyeleven theme. Here is the [link](http://tinkerbin.com/8eZz24PN) for the reference . Here you can see when you hover on menu it will show the dropdown . But you can see there is a gap in between parent menu(company) and sub menu. So how to clear that? Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have a margin of 4px on the dropdown.

You need to change `margin: 4px;` on `#access a {`, which sets the margin all around the `<a>` tag, including underneath it. Change it to `margin: 4px 4px 0 4px;` which puts the margin on all sides except the bottom

Updated demo [here](http://tinkerbin.com/pda4PPlh)

Comment: Is the extended box-shadow part of the desired result? If you look closely the drop-down's box-shadow goes over the gray background of the navigation. It's one of the reasons why I removed the top-padding in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change some css:

```
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
  background: #FFF; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
  color: #373737;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

The margin-bottom has to be added.

The other answers change the original layout.

Update: padding-bottom added. it's 9px as we go up 4, we need to come down 8 plus 1 for the padding in `#access a`

Comment: This makes the navigation bar change size on mouseover and cause lots of buggy resizing when mousing over different sub menus

Answer (score -1):

Just change the following CSS declaration:

```
#access ul ul {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 193px;
  z-index: 99999;
  padding: 14px 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

To:

```
#access ul ul {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 193px;
  z-index: 99999;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Notice the change in `padding` and `top` properties and the addition of `background-color`.